# Most efficient way to update list items with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

Our users will have a `List<EmailRecords>` collection, and only one of which will be marked `(bool)IsPrimary = true`.

I'd like to write Entity Framework code to update this.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.EmailRecords 
SET IsPrimary = 1
WHERE EmailRecordId = @RecordId

UPDATE dbo.EmailRecords 
SET IsPrimary = 0 
WHERE EmailRecordId != @RecordId
     AND ParentRecordId = @ParentRecordId
```

My object is:

```
public class EmailRecords
{
    public int EmailRecordId { get; set; }
    public int ParentRecordId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this with Entity Framework?

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
foreach (var thisRecord in profile.EmailRecords)
{
    if (thisRecord.EmailRecordId == thisId)
    {
        thisRecord.IsPrimary = true;
    }
    else
    {
        thisRecord.IsPrimary = false;
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What is your .net list collection named?  Provide some code.

Comment: Do you mean linq2sql or entity framework?

Comment: Hi. So you might have noticed a couple of downvotes on the question already. Reason being the fact that question currently sounds like "here is the idea, code it for me please". To get a good answer you should try do something yourself first, and then post here if you encounter specific problems, so that question sounds like "i have this problem, tried this to solve it, but got this error/issue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for C# code, something along these lines?

```
foreach(var record in profile.EmailRecords)
{
    record.IsPrimary = record.EmailRecordId == recordId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this example model you've given.

```
public class EmailRecords
{
    public int EmailRecordId { get; set; }
    public int ParentRecordId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

You can unset this primary behavior using this combination of LINQ and code.

```
// Change this Int32 to match your @RecordId and @ParentRecordId.  Possibly parameterize this entire code snippet into a method.
Int32 recordIdToChange = 1;
Int32 parentRecordIdToChange = 1;

// Set the new primary.
EmailRecords emailRecordToSetToPrimary = profile.EmailRecords.Where(cs => cs.EmailRecordId == recordIdToChange).FirstOrDefault();
if (emailRecordToSetToPrimary != null){
   emailRecordToSetToPrimary.IsPrimary = true;
}

// Only unset those records whose id does not match the new primary AND is currently set as a primary.
List<EmailRecords> emailRecordsToUnsetFromPrimary = profile.EmailRecords.Where(cs => cs.EmailRecordId != recordIdToChange && cs.IsPrimary == true && cs.ParentRecordId == parentRecordIdToChange).ToList();
foreach (EmailRecords emailRecordToUnsetFromPrimary in emailRecordsToUnsetFromPrimary){
   emailRecordToUnsetFromPrimary.IsPrimary = false;
}

// Perform your save on the emailRecords list collection.
```

Comment: This `emailRecords.Where(cs => cs.EmailRecordId == recordIdToChange).FirstOrDefault();` could also be further simplified to `emailRecords.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.EmailRecordId == recordIdToChange);` - no need for `.Where()` first and then a `.FirstOrDefault()` after that ...